# function returning bool works even though it returns 1 or 0

Tags: c++

```
bool CWaypoint::less(CWaypoint const &wp_right)
{
    bool result;
    CWaypoint temp1;

    (calculateDistance(temp1) > temp1.calculateDistance(wp_right)) ?
            result = 1 : result = 0;

    return result;
}
```

why don't I get an error even when I am not returning a bool type ?

Comment: Some compilers might give you a warning for this (or have an option to do so), but they can't give you an error, because this is a perfectly valid implicit conversion. (And it's useful in a lot of cases.)

Comment: As a side note, why are you using a ternary expression for side effects and ignoring its value? Is your `f` key broken so you can't type `if`?

Comment: You *are* returning a `bool` (the return type of your function is `bool` and `result` is a `bool`). You are setting `result` from `int` literals.

Comment: This isn't what you asked about, but the last several lines are more simply written as `return calculateDistance(temp1) > temp1.calculateDistance(wp_right);`

Comment: Or, if you want to use a variable with the `?:` operator, at least put the assignment portion before the operator, have the operator only decide on the value to be assigned: `result = (calculateDistance(temp1) > temp1.calculateDistance(wp_right)) ? 1 : 0;`
`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An integer-to-boolean conversion takes place. From the C++ standard:

> **4.12 Boolean conversions [conv.bool]**
>
> A prvalue of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, pointer, or pointer to member type can be converted to a
> prvalue of type **bool**. A zero value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted to **false**;
> any other value is converted to **true**.

Comment: The answer is entirely correct. This is an oddity of C++ that you have to learn to deal with: implicit integer to bool conversion.

Comment: @user3344003 I thought it was common to many languages, although maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: It is common in C-based languages. You can't use an integer as a Boolean in, say, Ada or Pascal without an explicit conversion.